# How to know if a share has been liked by the company page itself?

Tags: linkedin-api

Is it possible to know if a company page has liked a share/ugcPost/comment without listing all the share/ugcPost/comment likes?

Here is the related documentation about retrieving the `Summary of Social Actions`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/network-update-social-actions#retrieve-a-summary-of-social-actions

Please note that the field `likedByCurrentUser` is `true` if the user represented by the Access Token has liked the page (not the page itself, which I would like to know).

I would like to get this information easily if possible (I mean without listing all the likes), because on my application I would like to implement the like feature but as the company page.

Best regards.